# How to enable ffmpeg php extention in Cent OS 6.5 server with php 5.5

Tags: php, video, centos6.5, ffmpeg

I need to create a screenshot from a video.

I have followed [this](http://myownhomeserver.com/2012/02/how-to-install-ffmpeg-php-for-windows-apache-http-server/) tutorial to do the initial setup in Windows 8, php 5.3.

1. I downloaded the ffmpeg from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) for 64 bit operating system.
2. I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gU49GiWGGAI) and did all configuration successfully and `phpinfo()` shows that `ffmpeg` has been installed.
3. Then, I tried [this](http://pastebin.com/r8JDpxnL) to find out whether it is working or not. It worked successfully.
4. Next I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qT4hN5o57hI) video tutorial and thumbnails were created successfully.

Below is my code:

```
/**
 * FFMPEG-PHP Test Script
 *
 * Special thanks to http://www.sajithmr.me/ffmpeg-sample-code for this code example!
 * See the tutorial at http://myownhomeserver.com on how to install ffmpeg-php.
 */
error_reporting(1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
// Check if the ffmpeg-php extension is loaded first
extension_loaded('ffmpeg') or die('Error in loading ffmpeg');

// Determine the full path for our video
$vid = realpath('./videos/myvideo.mp4');
$videosize = filesize($vid);
$remoteVideo = 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4';

//ffmpeg

$ffmpeg = dirname(__FILE__) . "\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
$imageFile = "1.png";
$image2 = "2.png";
$size = "120x90";
$getfromsecond = 7;
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $vid -an -ss $getfromsecond -s $size $imageFile";
$cmd2 = "$ffmpeg -i $remoteVideo -an -ss $getfromsecond -s $size $image2";
if(!shell_exec($cmd)){
    echo "Thumbnail created";
}else{
    echo "Error Creating thumbnail";
}

if(!shell_exec($cmd2)){
    echo "Thumbnail for remote url was created";
}else{
    echo "Error Creating thumbnail for remote url ";
}
```

Output:

```
Thumbnail created
Thumbnail for remote url was created
```

Now, the above code works as expected locally on my Windows machine. I need to do it in my server environment (Linux server) with php 5.5.

How do I do the configuration for ffmpeg on CentOS release 6.5 server with php 5.5.

I have followed these tutorials to install it on the server:

1. http://supportlobby.com/blog/ffmpeg-installation-on-centos-6-5/
2. http://tecadmin.net/install-ffmpeg-on-linux/

Output in console:

```
[root@BRANDWEB01D ~]# ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 2.2.1
built on Apr 13 2014 13:00:18 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --enable-vdpau --disable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --disable-stripping
libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[root@BRANDWEB01D ~]# which ffmpeg
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
[root@BRANDWEB01D ~]# ffmpeg -formats
ffmpeg version 2.2.1 Copyright (coffee) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 13 2014 13:00:18 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --enable-vdpau --disable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --disable-stripping
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
File formats:
 D. = Demuxing supported
 .E = Muxing supported
```

**However, on the server when I open my php file, I am getting the following error:**

> Error in loading ffmpeg

I have checked `phpinfo()` and it shows ffmpeg installed in my local but not in server.

What else do I need to do to enable ffmpeg extension in Cent Os 6.5 and php 5.5?